# Java - remove last known item from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

OK, so here is my `ArrayList`:

```
private List<ClientThread> clients = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
```

and here is what I am trying to do:
I am trying to remove the last known item from the `ArrayList` I posted above. I'm trying to do this with the code below:

```
    } catch(SocketException re) {


                            String hey = clients.get(clients.size());
                            ClientThread.remove(hey);
                            System.out.println(hey + " has logged out.");
                            System.out.println("CONNECTED PLAYERS: " + clients.size());
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
C:\wamp\www\mystikrpg\Server.java:147: incompatible types
found   : Server.ClientThread
required: java.lang.String
                        String hey = clients.get(clients.size());
                                                ^
C:\wamp\www\mystikrpg\Server.java:148: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method remove(java.lang.String)
location: class Server.ClientThread
                        ClientThread.remove(hey);
                                    ^
2 errors
```

What am I doing wrong?
It's supposed to remove the last known item from my `ArrayList`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing last object of ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987727/removing-last-object-of-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It should be:

```
ClientThread hey = clients.get(clients.size() - 1);
clients.remove(hey);
```

Or you can do

```
clients.remove(clients.size() - 1);
```

The minus ones are because size() returns the number of elements, but the ArrayList's first element's index is 0 and not 1.

Comment: Note that when overriding `.equals()` you may want to use the latter version to ensure it’s really the last object that gets removed.

Comment: I believe your first solution wouldn't work properly if there were duplicates in the list. However, there might as well be situations when you desire such functionality.

Comment: It should be noted that removing an Object from an array list is O(n). The second approach is constant time.

Comment: here a explaination of the differences above https://xenovation.com/blog/development/java/remove-last-element-from-list-java

Answer (score 8):

The compiler complains that you are trying something of a list of `ClientThread` objects to a `String`. Either change the type of `hey` to `ClientThread` or `clients` to `List<String>`.

In addition: Valid indices for lists are from 0 to size()-1.

So you probably want to write

```
   String hey = clients.get(clients.size()-1);
```

Comment: +1 for realizing that the the index passed to `get()` was wrong, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 6):

This line means you instantiated a "List of ClientThread Objects".

```
private List<ClientThread> clients = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
```

This line has two problems.

```
String hey = clients.get(clients.size());
```

**1.** This part of the line:

```
clients.get(clients.size());
```

**ALWAYS** throws **IndexOutOfBoundsException** because a collections size is always one bigger than its last elements index;

**2.** Compiler complains about incompatible types because you cant assign a ClientThread object to String object. Correct one should be like this.

```
ClientThread hey = clients.get(clients.size()-1);
```

Last but not least. If you know index of the object to remove just write

```
 clients.remove(23); //Lets say it is in 23. index
```

Don't write

```
   ClientThread hey = clients.get(23); 

   clients.remove(hey);
```

because you are forcing the list to search for the index that you already know.
If you plan to do something with the removed object later. Write

```
   ClientThread hey = clients.remove(23);
```

This way you can remove the object and get a reference to it at the same line.

Bonus: Never ever call your instance variable with name "hey". Find something meaningful.

And Here is your corrected and ready-to-run code:

```
public class ListExampleForDan {

    private List<ClientThread> clients = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        clients.add(new ClientThread("First and Last Client Thread"));

        boolean success = removeLastElement(clients);

        if (success) {

            System.out.println("Last Element Removed.");

        } else {

            System.out.println("List Is Null/Empty, Operation Failed.");

        }

    }

    public static boolean removeLastElement(List clients) {

        if (clients == null || clients.isEmpty()) {

            return false;

        } else {

            clients.remove(clients.size() - 1);

            return true;

        }

    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to assign the return value of `clients.get(clients.size())` to the string `hey`, but the object returned is a `ClientThread`, not a string. As [Andre mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515496/java-remove-last-known-item-from-arraylist/3515563#3515563), you need to use the proper index as well.

As far as your second error is concerned, there is no static method `remove()` on the type `ClientThread`. Really, you likely wanted the remove method of your `List` instance, `clients`.

You can remove the last item from the list, if there is one, as follows. Since remove also returns the object that was removed, you can capture the return and use it to print out the name:

```
int size = clients.size();

if (size > 0) {
    ClientThread client = clients.remove(size - 1);

    System.out.println(client + " has logged out.");
    System.out.println("CONNECTED PLAYERS: " + clients.size());
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `.remove()` on the right object. Imaginary extra +1 for using the return value from remove().

Answer (score 2):

`clients.get` will return a `ClientThread` and not a `String`, and it will bomb with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if it would compile as Java is zero based for indexing.

Similarly I think you should call `remove` on the `clients` list.

```
ClientThread hey = clients.get(clients.size()-1);
clients.remove(hey);
System.out.println(hey + " has logged out.");
System.out.println("CONNECTED PLAYERS: " + clients.size());
```

I would use the stack functions of a [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) in this case though.

```
ClientThread hey = clients.removeLast()
```

Answer (score 0):

First error: You're casting a `ClientThread` as a `String` for some reason.

Second error: You're not calling `remove` on your `List`.

Is is homework? If so, you might want to use the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand [java generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf). You have a list of `ClientThread` but trying to get `String`. You have other errors, but this one is very basic.