# Removing last object of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist

I want to remove the last object from an `ArrayList` quickly.

I know that `remove(Object O)` takes `O(n)` in an `ArrayList`, but I wonder if it is possible to do this in constant time since I just want to remove the **last** object?

Comment: There is also `remove(int)`...

Comment: `list.remove(list.size()-1)` !!!

Comment: Would a stack be a better solution here?

Comment: Removing the last element is a constant time operation since no elements needed to be shifted to the left

Comment: Continuing from @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot comment, remember that [big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) represents the *upper* bound, better known as the worst case.

Comment: First things first, if you are attempting to remove an element based on position (last) do not use the `remove` element that searches the list and might remove from any position.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot You should have posted that as an answer... D:

Comment: @thegrinner: "big-o" != "worst-case".

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I know how the syntax looks like , the question (Which is answered by Wchargin), is about the time complexity ! not the syntax

Comment: @Arian Hosseinzadeh , Ok if you knew the syntax then probably I assume that you would have gone through its implementation code-wise before asking this here , if not , then it is a bad question showing no effort on your part :)

Comment: @TheNewIdiot : if you look at the answer , you see that they say remove(int index) takes O(n) time , this was the effort I made :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540511/time-complexity-for-java-arraylist

Comment: @thegrinner No it doesn't. It represents the average. Consider a hash lookup: *O(1)* on average, but worst case *O(N).* QuikSort: *O(N*log(N))* on average, worst case *O(N^2).*

Comment: @JohnB He isn't using a searching `remove()`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

See [the documentation for `ArrayList#remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29), as in the following syntax:

```
list.remove(list.size() - 1)
```

Here is how it's implemented. `elementData` does a lookup on the backing array (so it can cut it loose from the array), which should be constant time (since the JVM knows the size of an object reference and the number of entries it can calculate the offset), and `numMoved` is `0` for this case:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index); // throws an exception if out of bounds

    modCount++;        // each time a structural change happens
                       // used for ConcurrentModificationExceptions

    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Comment: O1 for this? arraycopy entire up to, or just cutting the array loose from end ?

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 21, simply using [`List.removeLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeLast()), for example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3));

System.out.println(list.removeLast()); // 3 - removes and returns the last element
```

**Note:** if the list is not empty, the implementation of `List.removeLast` returns the result of calling `remove(size() - 1)`. Otherwise, it throws `NoSuchElementException`.

The time complexity of removing the last element from `ArrayList` is O(1) - it is just decrementing the size of the list by 1 under the hood.

Answer (score -2):

Just simply use.

```
arraylist.remove(arraylist.size() - 1)
```

Comment: that was answered already (I promise I wasn't  the one who downvoted you, but that's probably why somebody did).

Comment: The question is whether it is possible to do it in constant time, and you haven't answered that.