# Remove last element of a list

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been tasked to do the below in a newbie Java tutorial on ArrayList

```
// 1) Declare am ArrayList of strings
    // 2) Call the add method and add 10 random strings
    // 3) Iterate through all the elements in the ArrayList
    // 4) Remove the first and last element of the ArrayList
    // 5) Iterate through all the elements in the ArrayList, again.
```

Below is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ex1_BasicArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
            Random rand = new Random();
            String randy = String.valueOf(rand);
            list.add(randy );
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
        }   
        list.remove(0);
        list.remove(list.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs, but I get the below error message when it runs. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
java.util.Random@7852e922java.util.Random@4e25154fjava.util.Random@70dea4ejava.util.Random@5c647e05java.util.Random@33909752java.util.Random@55f96302java.util.Random@3d4eac69java.util.Random@42a57993java.util.Random@75b84c92java.util.Random@6bc7c054Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at apollo.exercises.ch08_collections.Ex1_BasicArrayList.main(Ex1_BasicArrayList.java:23)
```

Comment: Your solution for task `2` is very interesting :D.

Comment: @Tom haha... interesting? Is there a way I could have done it better?

Comment: Yes, by creating real random String and not just the output of `instanceOfRandomClass.toString()`.

Comment: @Tom Hmm I'm not sure what that is... but I'll look it up and implement it into my code :) Thanks for the tip

Comment: You can search on Stackoverflow for that. There are some questions (and answers) about random strings in Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing last object of ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987727/removing-last-object-of-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`List` indices go from `0` to `list.size() - 1`. Exceeding the upper bound results in the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
list.remove(list.size() - 1);
```

Comment: It would be great if Java had a dedicated function for this, like pop_back() in std::vector in C++

Comment: yeah, some neat functions are missing, here are some examples explained https://xenovation.com/blog/development/java/remove-last-element-from-list-java

Answer (score 4):

### `List#removeLast`

As of Java 21, you can now use [removeLast()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeLast()).

> Removes and returns the last element of this collection (optional operation).

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeLast()

Answer (score 3):

Your list has 11 elements, their indices are 0-10. When you call `list.remove(list.size());`, you are telling it to remove the element at index 11 (because the size of the list is 11), but that index is out of bounds.

The index of the last element of any list is always `list.size() - 1`.